# How can I call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() asynchronously, while being notified of its completion?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-mediascanner

I want to collect some information from the MediaStore. Sometimes a .nomedia file results in a file not being scanned, and so I use an explicit call to be sure the file was scanned!

So I'm calling

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(Context activity, String[] path, 
   String[] mimeTypes, OnScanCompletedListener oscl);
```

...to force the scan. However, this can take a while, so I'd like to run it in the background...

I ran into a couple of issues trying to accomplish this:

- First, I tried call the MediaScannerConnection from a new thread, but this didn't work because the scanner is earliest started after ending the activity. I think "Context activity" parameter will cause to start after ending this activity.
- Second to wait for the result inside another thread is not always ok, because it depends on the result how to continue.

Therefore both ways don't work. :-(

**So my question is:** How to start `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` in a thread other than the activity thread? If this is not possible, what's the best practice to accomplish asynchronous processing? IMHO, waiting must happen inside a new thread, but then it's too late to use the result for deciding how to continue.

---

#### Sample for first try - never a result returns:

```
Log.d(TAG, "MAIN: ID of the main thread ... " 
      + Thread.currentThread().getId());
final Object o = new Object();

Thread scannerThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "SCAN: scanner thread is started ... (thread id: " 
      + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ")");
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ActivityPlayer.this, new String[] { 
         mp3File.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
         new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
             Log.d(TAG, "SCAN: the onScanCompleted is called! (" + path + ")");
             synchronized (o) {
               o.notifyAll();
               Log.d(TAG, "SCAN: notify is successful executed!");
             }
           }
         });
         Log.d(TAG, "SCAN: MediaScanner is called");
       }
     };         
     Log.d(TAG, "MAIN: start scanning thread");
     scannerThread.start();

     synchronized (o) {
       try {
         Log.d(TAG, 
               "WAITER: Start: Waiting - for the notify of this object o!");
         o.wait();
         Log.d(TAG, "WAITER: End: Waiting - the notify happened!");
       } catch (Exception e) { // InterruptedException
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
```

#### Sample for second try:

```
Log.d(TAG, "MAIN: ID of the main thread ... " 
      + Thread.currentThread().getId());
final Object o = new Object();

// call scanner ...
Log.d(TAG, "scanning of file started ...");
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ActivityPlayer.this, 
        new String[] {mp3File.getAbsolutePath() }, 
        null,   
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.d(TAG, "the onScanCompleted is called! (" + path + ")");
            synchronized (o) {
              o.notifyAll();
              Log.d(TAG, "notify is successful executed!");
            }
          }
        });
// Start thread for waiting ...
Thread waiterThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "WAITER: waiter thread is started!");
    synchronized (o) {
      try {
        Log.d(TAG, 
              "WAITER: Start: Waiting - for the notify of this object o!");
        o.wait();
        Log.d(TAG, "WAITER: End: Waiting - the notify happened!");
      } catch (Exception e) { // InterruptedException
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
};
waiterThread.start();
Log.d(TAG, "MAIN: ended things ... ");
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with a good idea to solve this problem!

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ at http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @Sameera: please read [In defense of editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) - in short, **don't bother editing for trivial matters like signatures unless you're also taking the time to fix more serious problems** like titles, grammar, and formatting (please see the edits by Grillz and myself for an illustration of how much additional editing this post needed). When the rest of a long question is hard to read, when the title is unclear, removing the signature is pointless. Also, if you're going to leave a comment, **be diplomatic about it.**

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks Shog, I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
public class MediaLibraryHelper {
    public interface OnMediaScanListener{
        void onError();
        void onSuccess(Uri uri);
    }

    private MediaScannerConnection conn;
    private Context context;
    public MediaLibraryHelper(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void scanFile(final File file,final OnMediaScanListener lis){
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.disconnect();

        if(!file.isFile()){
            lis.onError();
            return;
        }

        conn=new MediaScannerConnection(context,new MediaScannerConnectionClient(){


            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                conn.scanFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),null);
            }


            public void onScanCompleted(String arg0, Uri arg1) {
                conn.disconnect();
                if(arg1==null){
                    lis.onError();
                }
                lis.onSuccess(arg1);

            }});
        conn.connect();
    }


}
```